# Migrating multiple quality branches from VSS to TFS

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, tfs

I'm in the middle of a TFS migration and I'm looking for the best practices on how to migrate multiple branches (in this case quality branches like DEV, PRE, PROD) from VSS to TFS. Most of the documentation on the migration strategies seems to only address moving one branch to TFS, then creating branches off of that. The problem with moving the three different branches is that they wouldn't have a link in TFS until I created it, which would then require a baseless merge to initially establish a relationship. Some have suggested using rollbacks, but that seems to mess with our history migration.

Does anyone have experience with this or a recommended strategy?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Baseless merge is the way to go.  Basically migrate the whole source tree without setting up branches and then define them once the migration is complete.

I've got a [blog post](http://www.richard-banks.org/2010/09/how-to-fix-branches-after-migration-to.html) showing how this is done.  Have a look and see if that helps you.

Comment: As long as you have an existing branch relationship or you do a baseless merge, you should be able to reparent.  Keep in mind that you can do a baseless merge with no files selected just to set up the relationship, and also remember than nested branches aren't supported.